# how can i use Nlog to create files with different name by using the values at runtime?

Tags: c#, nlog

I have a case where i need to create separate file for different types of data coming into my system, i want to use NLog to make sure each event type is stored in its own event type file. for instance 
for events a,b,c,a i want all a events to be logged in file with name a.txt , all b events to be logged in file b.txt.

C# code

```
string[] events= { "a", "b", "c", "a" };
            foreach(string et in events)
            {
                NLog.LogManager.Configuration.Variables["filename"] = et ;
                LogManager.ReconfigExistingLoggers();
                logger.Warn(filename);
            }
```

Here is my Nlog.config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>

<nlog xmlns="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <variable name ="filename" value="test"></variable>
  <targets>
    <target name="logfile" xsi:type="File" filename="${filename}.txt" />
    <target name="logconsole" xsi:type="Console" />
  </targets>

  <rules>
    <logger name="*" minlevel="Info" writeTo="logconsole" />
    <logger name="*" minlevel="Debug" writeTo="logfile" />
  </rules>
</nlog>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should not use the global NLog Config Variables to transfer local context. Instead you should use the recommended ways to handle context in NLog:

https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Context

For example you could create a Logger object for every event-type you have:

```
var loggerA = NLog.LogManager.GetLogger("a");
loggerA.Info("Hello from a");
loggerA.Info("Goodbye from a");
var loggerB = NLog.LogManager.GetLogger("b");
loggerB.Info("Hello from b");
loggerB.Info("Goodbye from b");
```

And use `${logger}` in the NLog FileTarget FileName:

```
<target name="logfile" xsi:type="File" filename="${logger}.txt" />
```

You could also add a custom property to your Logger using Logger.WithProperty and use that Logger for all your events:

```
var loggerPropA = NLog.LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger().WithProperty("EventType", "a");
loggerPropA.Info("Hello from a");
loggerPropA.Info("Goodbye from a");
var loggerPropB = NLog.LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger().WithProperty("EventType", "b");
loggerPropB.Info("Hello from b");
loggerPropB.Info("Goodbye from b");
```

And use `${event-properties:EventType}` in the NLog FileTarget FileName:

```
<target name="logfile" xsi:type="File" filename="${event-properties:EventType:whenEmpty=App}.txt" />
```

Depending on how many active EventTypes you have (2 or 200) and their lifetime (2 min or 2 days), then you might want to study these NLog FileTarget options:

- openFileCacheTimeout
- openFileCacheSize

See also https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/File-target

Comment: This is pretty cool. Could you please ellaborate this statement: "You should not use the global NLog Config Variables to transfer local context"?  What do you mean by "transfer local context"?

Comment: @MikeDinescu One should always be careful with global variables for mutable state. They will bite you really hard. Especially when in a multi-threaded environment, which is easy to activate in NLog with `<targets async="true">`. See also https://www.google.com/search?q=global+variables+mutable+state

Comment: @MikeDinescu I guess one could also translate "transfer local context" into "capture local state" (English is not my native language)

Comment: No worries about the language. So basically you were saying that if you want to update the config at runtime, multiple times, that is a potential problem due to concurrent access to the log config which is global, right? I found this use case very different from the traditional logging scenarios I'm used too. To the point that I question NLog being the right tool for the job, but perhaps I am wrong

Comment: @MikeDinescu How did we get from it is a bad idea to use global variables to capture local state. To that NLog config cannot be changed at runtime? You can add/remove targets and logging-rules if you want while the NLog engine is running. (Just remember `ReconfigureExistingLoggers` when done, and it is "bad" idea to re-assign `LogManager.Configuration` as closing / re-initializing targets)

Comment: not saying you can't modify the config (to add remove targets) - i'm questioning whether it is a good idea

Comment: I think changing the NLog config during the lifetime of the application is an extraordinary event, and it pollutes the actual application-logic. That one suddenly fiddles with adding/removing NLog targets or changing NLog logging rules. Which is why I really like the NLog layout-logic and filter-logic as it provides a lot of power and keeps the NLog specific details in the application to a minimum (stuff stays in the `NLog.config`)

Comment: Thanks rolf and mike for helping with the solution. The solution indeed solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can define a rule that matches the event type and writes to a different file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>

<nlog xmlns="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <targets>
    <target name="logfile" xsi:type="File" filename="log.txt" />
    <target name="log_a" xsi:type="File" filename="a.txt" />
    <target name="log_b" xsi:type="File" filename="b.txt" />
    <target name="log_c" xsi:type="File" filename="c.txt" />
    <target name="logconsole" xsi:type="Console" />
  </targets>

  <rules>
    <logger name="*" minlevel="Info" writeTo="logconsole" />
    <!-- now add overrides for the log sources you want written to separate files -->
    <!-- order of the rules is important, because we're setting final = True --> 
    <logger name="a" minlevel="Debug" writeTo="log_a" final="True"/>
    <logger name="b" minlevel="Debug" writeTo="log_b" final="True"/>
    <logger name="c" minlevel="Debug" writeTo="log_c" final="True"/>
    <!-- anything not matched above will go to the general log file -->
    <logger name="*" minlevel="Debug" writeTo="logfile" />
  </rules>
</nlog>
```

I hope this helps. You can also do the same with code:

```
var config = new NLog.Config.LoggingConfiguration();

var logfile = new NLog.Targets.FileTarget()
{
    Name = "logfile",
    FileName = "logfile.txt"
}

var logconsole = new NLog.Targets.ColoredConsoleTarget() {
    Name = "logconsole"
    // other options here..
};
config.AddTarget(logconsole);
config.AddRule(NLog.LogLevel.Info, NLog.LogLevel.Fatal, logconsole, "*");


foreach (var et in events) {
  var target = new NLog.Targets.FileTarget() {
    Name = "log_" + et,
    FileName = et + ".txt"
  };
  config.AddTarget(target);
  config.AddRule(NLog.LogLevel.Info, NLog.LogLevel.Fatal, target, et, final: true);
}
config.AddTarget(logfile);
config.AddRule(NLog.LogLevel.Debug, NLog.LogLevel.Fatal, logfile, "*");                    

NLog.LogManager.Configuration = config;
```

I've never tried but perhaps you can update the configuration multiple times, at runtime, as you find new events to add. Give it a try.

Comment: Hey mike, this would work with static data, however in my case the events are all dynamic in nature and a new event can occur any moment. With the above approach i need to create the target and define loggers at runtime. I was hoping for a generic way where these are handled using a placeholder whose value is being decided at runtime.

Comment: You can define the logging rules dynamically, at runtime. I'll update the answer to show how you could do that. By dynamic, I mean at startup. But if the logging sources are expected to change at runtime, I'm not really sure how that would work with NLog. What you're trying to do is pretty unusual

Comment: I would probably make use of the ability that NLog FileTarget has support for NLog Layout in its FileName-property.