# Why are my logs from different Loggers in different Threads writing to the same logfile?

Tags: c#, logging, nlog

Hi I want to write to different log files from different threads. Each thread should have it's own log file. I have looked at some solutions under this topic and haven't found something that works for me. Especially since I am new to nLog and don't know how to make an nlog config file. Instead I configure my nLog programmatically.

My problem, I have the following set up for my main class and program:

```
namespace TDXXMLParser
{

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var funcName = nameof(Main);
            //Logger details
            try
            {
                LaunchFolderMode();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Logger.Error(ex, "Error while running the function '{funcName}()': ", funcName);
            }

        }

        public void CreateLogger(string toolType, string dbToolTypes)
        {
            var config = new LoggingConfiguration();
            var fileTarget = new FileTarget($"{toolType}_logfile");
            config.AddTarget(fileTarget);
            string logFileName;
            logFileName = $"{toolType}_logfile"
            var currentday = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
            var fileName = logFileName + $"_{currentday}.log";
            fileTarget.FileName = fileName;
            fileTarget.Layout = "${longdate}|${level: uppercase = true}|${logger}|${message: withexception = true}";
            fileTarget.ArchiveAboveSize = 1048576 * 100;  // 1 mb = 1048576 bytes
            fileTarget.ArchiveNumbering = ArchiveNumberingMode.Sequence;
            config.AddRuleForAllLevels(fileTarget);
            LogManager.Configuration = config;          //save configuration

            //return LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger();
        }

        private static void LaunchFolderMode()
        {
            //get new files and load to db. wait for all of them to finish first
            var filesToProcess = new HashSet<string>()
            {
                @"C:\TestPath2\AAL_WSM_WSM101_D1338850_2068_JGR0D174TMD5_1A_20220315050208319.xml.gz",
                @"C:\TestPath2\SDA_CIM_CIM303_D2042100_850315_0239155823_1A_20221006095528570.xml.gz"
            };
            Parallel.ForEach(filesToProcess, new ParallelOptions{MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 2} ,tdxFile =>
            {
                string FileNameActual = Path.GetFileName(tdxFile);
                string[] givenFileInfo = FileNameActual.Split('_');
                string toolType = givenFileInfo[2].Substring(0, 3);
                string dbToolTypes = givenFileInfo[2].Substring(0, 3);
                //string givenFileFullPath = args[0];
                Program pInstance = new Program();
                pInstance.CreateLogger(toolType,dbToolTypes);
                TDXItemHandler parser = new TDXItemHandler();
                parser.ProcessItem(toolType, dbToolTypes, tdxFile);
            });
        }

    }
}
```

The above code is supposed to create two different log file targets and two seperate log files which it does. The issue starts when I enter the foreach loop and call the following function in parallel:

```
public class TDXItemHandler
{
    
    public  void ProcessItem(string toolType, string dbtoolTypes, string fileName)
    {
        var funcName = nameof(ProcessItem);
        var Logger = LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger();
        //do stuff
        Logger.Info("Started new file processing");
        Logger.Info("Started processing {processItem} for Tooltype= {tooltype}", FileNameToProcess, dbtoolType);
        // do stuff
    }
}
```

The issue is that even though I create a new Logger for each instance of ProcessItem(), the logging targets doesn't stay independent of each other.

```
Logger.Info("Started processing {processItem} for Tooltype= {tooltype}", FileNameToProcess, dbtoolType);
```

Displays only on the last acquired logger from the previous CreateLogger method. Instead of sticking with it's own logger, it is replaced with the second logger. So my CIM file logs is written in the WSM log if the WSM logger is created last. Why is this happening? And how can I fix it to make them independent?  Unless there is a better logger for C#?

Comment: See also: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60907378/193178

Answer (score 0):

You should only assign NLog Configuration once at application startup. Instead of assigning multiple times in a loop, then you should just assign the necessary [context](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Context).

Example of using Logger-name as filename:

```
fileTarget.FileName = "${logger:shortName=true}_${shortdate}.log";
```

And then create an unique-logger for each `toolType`. Ex:

```
public  void ProcessItem(string toolType, string dbtoolTypes, string fileName)
{
    var funcName = nameof(ProcessItem);
    var Logger = LogManager.GetLogger($"{funcName}.{toolType}");
```

See also: https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Logger-Layout-Renderer

See also: https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Tutorial

Comment: So the Process Item calls several functions that have loggers in them. Wouldn't using {funcName}.{toolType}  cause it to create a new log file for each function? 

And I used Nlog configuration in a loop because I wanted each tool to have it's own filetarget and therefore logs

Comment: @edo101 The same filetarget can write to several filenames. See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/60907378/193178

Comment: Yes it can. The issue that they are writing over each other. one tool writes in the other's log file despite having it's own filetarget and filename and vice versa

Comment: @edo101 Again you should only assign NLog Configuration once, and not multiple times.